# Whats the pros and cons of RPCs vs. HTTP in information exchange in microservice architectures?

Tags: microservices, distributed-system

What type of components could benefit from RPC over HTTP, vice-versa? Does there exist other information exchange mechanisms, what are their use?

I've seen smart people use both, I'm sure for reasons I don't quiet understand.  Thanks.

Comment: Checkout Protocol Buffers and how they also supplier HTTP/2. This might inspire you.

Comment: see [What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43682366

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of exposing APIs via HTTP is language interoperablity. Origoinally javascript but also with other scripting laguages.

All languages these days offer simple methods of making http calls, so using http allows your api to be consumed in situations where creating a full client would be onorous.

eg. webpages, bat, bash or powershell scripts, excel macros or other products which allow intergration via a simple script.